# How to completely get rid of if-else with OOP in such a tree like structure?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

Here is the psudeocode:

```
if (parttimeEmployee) {
    if (country == USA) {

    } 
    if (country == UK {

    }
}

if (fullTimeEmployee) {
    if (country == USA) {

    } 
    if (country == UK) {

    }
}
```

Now,  partTime and fullTime employees can be subclassed from 'Employee' interface.

But we have another if-else repeated/replicated inside each of them for 'Country'

Which design-pattern can we use to completely replace such nested-conditions ?

Comment: It is important to know what's there inside each `if` on country.

Answer (score 1):

You can use composition, giving each employee a `Country` object, on which you can call a method, which would implement the correct behavior for that country, assuming the behavior is the same regardless of which subclass of Employee it is (full or part time). If you're operating on a combination of employee type and country to define the behavior, you'll have to either have the branches somewhere, or have a mess of `FullTimeUSEmployee`, `PartTimeUSEmployee`, `FullTimeUKEmployee`, etc and so on.

It's important to consider though if using any particular design pattern is actually improving your code; nested conditionals may be simpler and easier to work with than a big, complicated class hierarchy with composites. Personally, I'd keep the branches unless there's duplicate code within them, and if there is, move the duplicate code to a function/method so it can be reused - but I tend to care more about DRY than cyclomatic complexity.